# Run a method and countinue to the WebApp's lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifetime

There is an application that collects news from rss of news agencies maybe like Google Reader!. 
I want to call a method to update my links in DB in a period of the time and it continues to the Application life time.
something like a clock !!!
without any pause

I know some info about Threading 
but the problem is :

**Where can I call my Update method?**

I have some classes that some of them derive from others and I use to layer in my Project

I call the method in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateRss));
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

public void UpdateRss()
{
    while (true)
    {

        using (LinkService linkSrv = new LinkService())
        {
            linkSrv.UpdateLinksFromRSS();
        }
    }
}
```

and the definition of UpdateLinksFromRSS in LinkService is:

```
 public void UpdateLinksFromRSS()
{
    List<RssInfo> q;
    using (RssService RssSrv = new RssService())
    {
        q = RssSrv.GetRssInfoes();
    }
    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        AddLink(item);
    }
}
```

Honestly the problem is i have a property in BaseService that is defined like this:

```
 public static System.Web.Caching.Cache Cache
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.Cache; }
        }
```

when I run the project!
I got an error from this line: `return HttpContext.Current.Cache;`

Comment: What is this `BaseService` and what is the exact error you get?

Comment: BaseService is :public abstract class BaseService : IDisposable {} that contain that prop , my error is :'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' from that prop

Comment: http://www.img4up.com/up2/61955487714345908157.jpg

Comment: Have you tried accessing the ASP.NET cache via HttpRuntime.Cache instead?

Comment: tnx 4 ur response
how can i use HttpRuntime.Cache??